# PyCharm installs wrong version of pip in virtual environment

Tags: matplotlib, virtualenv, pycharm

EDIT: solved the core problem of installing `matplotlib` in the virtual environment (see my answer), but the original question of pip versions in PyCharm virtual environments might still deserve its own answer.

**Original Question**

All my Python projects are isolated in virtual environments. For the most part, PyCharm plays nice with virtualenv.

When trying to install a virtualenv using 2.7 as base interpreter, PyCharm installs the wrong pip to the virtual environment. As a result, although some packages install fine to the virtual environment, matplotlib does not install.

[image]

The interpreter for the bulk of my projects is 3.5, but for this one I need 2.7.

[image]

Is this a PyCharm bug, or something that can be fixed manually?

**What I tried**

I tried to open the virtual environment manually with `workon Jupyter2`, but because the environment is not in the usual Env folder, it wasn't found. I looked for a way to specify the path of an environment with `workon` but did not find one. *EDIT*: instead of `workon`, ran `activate` in the `Scripts` directory of the virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved the problem. Not accepting my answer because while it solves the numpy / matplotlib installations, which was the core problem, it does not answer the original question about pip versions in PyCharm -- which might still deserve an answer.

- navigate to the `Scripts` folder of the Env.
- command prompt: `activate.bat` to activate the Env.
- downloaded the wheel for `numpy` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and placed it at the root of the Env.
- in the shell for the virtual env, `cd` to the root of the Env, then pip installed the wheel, e.g. `pip install numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`
- from there, I was able to `pip install` `matplotlib` and `pandas`, but this step would have probably worked from PyCharm too.